# Problem using DropDownListFor in a simple situation (MVC 2.0)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I have that Class :

```
public Class Color
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller :

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var _colors = colorRepository.GetAll();
    return View(_colors);
}
```

So, my I have an IEnumerable strongly-typed View:

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<Color>>
```

How can I use **DropDownListFor** to show all Colors?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need **DropDownListFor**.
Just use DropDownList, if your model is like you described.

```
<% = Html.DropDownList("Colors", new SelectList(Model, "Id", "Name")) %>
```

If you do not like the strings try to build an extension method.

Something like this:

```
public static class MvcExtensions
{
    public static SelectList ToSelectList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list) where T : IDropdownList
    {
        IEnumerable<T> result;
        if (list == null)
        {
            result = (IEnumerable<T>) new List<EmptyDropdownList>{new EmptyDropdownList()};
        }
        else
        {
            result = list;
        }

        string value = Reflector.GetPropertyName<T>(x => x.Id);
        string text = Reflector.GetPropertyName<T>(x => x.Text);

        return new SelectList(result, value, text);
    }
}
```

The Reflector gets the property names by an convention based interface **IDropDownList**

```
public class Reflector
{
    public static string GetPropertyName<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
    {
        var lambdaEx = expression as LambdaExpression;
        if (lambdaEx == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("expression");

        MemberExpression memberExpression = null;

        if (lambdaEx.Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert)
        {
            var unaryExpression = lambdaEx.Body as UnaryExpression;
            if (unaryExpression == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("expression");

            if (unaryExpression.Operand.NodeType == ExpressionType.MemberAccess)
            {
                memberExpression = unaryExpression.Operand as MemberExpression;
            }
        }
        else if (lambdaEx.Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.MemberAccess)
        {
            memberExpression = lambdaEx.Body as MemberExpression;
        }

        if (memberExpression == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("expression");
            return memberExpression.Member.Name;
    }
}
```

Convention Interface

```
public interface IDropdownList
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Text { get; set; }
}
```

new Color class:

```
public class Color : IDropdownList
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Text { get; set; }
}
```

In the view you could write:

```
<% = Html.DropDownList("Colors", Model.ToSelectList())%>
```

Answer (score 1):

The **DropDownListFor** is a HtmlHelper to create a input field (of select type) for a given class property.

Suppose that you have a "Car" object:

```
class Car{
  public String ColorId{get;set;}
  public String Model{get;set;}
}
```

and you want to create a form to edit this kind of class.
In this case you will create a viewModel that contain the Car object and the **list of colors**.

```
class CarViewModel{
  public Car Car{ get; set; }
  public SelectList Colors { get; set; }
}
```

In the controller you create an instance of CarViewModel and populate it with values

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var viewModel = new CarViewModel();
    viewModel.Colors = new SelectList(colorRepository.GetAll(),"Id","Name");
    viewModel.Car = new Car();
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Then you pass the viewModel to a wiew strongly-typed on viewModel and inside that view you will use the **DropDownListFor** Helper

```
<% = Html.DropDownListFor(o=>o.ColorId, Model.Colors) %>
```